# how the tert command works for real numbers

Tags: dm-script

I like very much the tert() command in DigitalMicrograph but there is something I dont understand in it. Consider the test script:

```
image test:= realimage("",4,100,1);
number value1 = 1;
number value2 = 0.1;
if(value2==0.1) result("\nvalue2 really equals 0.1");
test.setPixel(5,0,value1);
test.setPixel(10,0,value2);

image mask = imageclone(test);
mask = 0;
mask = tert(test==value1,1,mask);
mask = tert(test==value2,1,mask);
mask.showimage()
```

The script finds the pixel where the "test" array equals to value1 but doesnot find this for value2. It seems the tert command understands the condition (test==value) only when the "value" is an integer number. Otherwise, it considers that the equivalence is not EXACT. That is strange because the number Value2 was implicitely (I assume) defined as a real number and then assigned to the real array.   How DigitalMicrograph decides whether the value is integer/real/double?

Comment: Just a little comment on syntax: `X = tert(A,B,C)` can also be written as `X = A ? B : C` which is sometimes easier to read (and also works with strings).

Answer (score 1):

What you have observed here is a typical problem when comparing floating point values without allowing a small but non-zero tolerance for the limited precision of floating-point representations.  In your specific test script, the problem arises because Number values in DMS are always double precision, so you are effectively comparing 4-byte float values in the test image with the 8-byte float values stored in the Number objects.  Your script will correctly find both values if you change the first line to allocate the test image with 8-byte floating-point values, as follows:

```
image test:= realimage("",8,100,1);
```

On the other hand, a more robust solution is to use a small non-zero tolerance when comparing floating point values for 'equality'.  Specifically, if you change the test lines of your script that invoke the tert function as follows, then it will also correctly find both values:

```
mask = tert(Abs((test-value1)/value1)<1e-7,1,mask);
mask = tert(Abs((test-value2)/value2)<1e-7,1,mask);
```